# C# StripLine (chart) drawing by click onto the chart

Tags: c#, charts

community,

this is my first question here. to all the other problems i had there was often a answer on this side. for this i did not find one. here is my problem:

i have a chart and i want to add a vertical starpline at the point i click the mouse on the chart. this i working so far with that code:

```
chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y), true);
double pX = chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position; //X Axis coordinate Mouse
            DataPoint dataPoint = chartSettlingCurve.Series[0].Points.FindByValue(nearestPreceedingValue(nearestPreceedingValue(pX)), "X");
            labelTab3Test.Text = Convert.ToString(dataPoint);

            DataPoint maxValuePoint = chartSettlingCurve.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue();

            StripLine stripLineEnd = new StripLine();
            stripLineEnd.BorderColor = Color.Blue;
            stripLineEnd.IntervalOffset = dataPoint.XValue;
            stripLineEnd.Text = "End";
```

this code generates a stripline at every point i click on the graph but i want just one line. so if ther still is a strip line it shopud be replaced by the new one at a other position.

woud be nice if you can help me. if you dont get my problem pleas ask.

thanks

Comment: What if you reuse stripLineEnd and only set its IntervalOffset OnClick? Or do you have to add the StripLine to the chart somewhere? If yes remove all StirpLines before adding the new.

Comment: hi, thx for your answer the problem is at the end i want to have two striplines (first called "stripLineStart" and the second is called "stripLineEnd") but the user shoud have the possibility to change both. so for example if the user is not happy with the position of "stiplineStart" he can change it but "stiplineEnd" should not be changed by a new positioning of striplineStart. if it helps you i can try to create some pictures. thx

Comment: Well then remember two striplines and remove/add new or edit intervalOffset of the stripline you want only. You should state which chart control you use and add at least all code of your click event handler method.

Comment: I try to erase the "striplineStart" with:                 
foreach (var element in chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(element.Tag.ToString());
                    if (element.Tag == "start")
                    {
                        element.Dispose();
                    }
                }
but this leads to runtime errors. How can I securely remove striplines? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a working solution is:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Count; j++)
            {
                if (chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines[j].Tag.ToString() == "end")
                {
                    chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.RemoveAt(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
```

or as an alternative:

```
            bool loop = true;
            while (loop)
            {
                loop = false;
                foreach (var element in chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines)
                {
                    if (element.Tag.ToString() == "end")
                    {
                        chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Remove(element);
                        loop = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all striplines using code below;

```
        while (chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Count > 0)
        {
            chartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Remove(hartSettlingCurve.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Last());   
        }
```

than you can add some code.